# How do I get the ath9k driver of backports-3.12-8 installed on Xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, backport, ath9k

I downloaded the 3.12-8 kernel files [linux-headers-all.deb, linux-headers-generic_i368.deb; linux-image-generic_i386.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.8-trusty/) from kernel.org and installed them via:

```
 dpkg -i *.deb
```

Now I'm trying to eliminate some wifi signal dropouts, which are probably caused by the driver itself. Apparently there have been some fixes to the ath9k driver, so I'd like to replace the default by a backports version.

I downloaded [backports-3.12.8-1.tar.gz](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.8/backports-3.12.8-1.tar.gz) from kernel.org and tried to get the ath9k module ready by:

```
cd ~/.source/backports-3.12.8-1/
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) /usr/src/linux
make defconfig-ath9k
```

This leaves me with following "missing-prototypes ERROR":

```
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
```

But when I continue with:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo make
sudo checkinstall
```

everything works!!!

So my questions are:

- Does this module depend on certain other kernel modules?

  > Yes following command does tell you:
  >
  > modinfo ath9k
- If so, where's information about that stuff?

  > Have a look at wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k.
- Is there a right way to install this kernel module resp. driver?

  > Probably by getting a pro in kernel compiling :-).

THX

Comment: Close Voters: This is *not* offtopic.  13.10 EOL'd on July 17, 2014.  When this question was posted, it was January 25, 2014.  We don't retroactively close just because that release went EOL, typically, unless the policy  has changed and it was not stated anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasW.: It's definitely not off topic for EOL, but it might be for being irreproducible considering the long time, since it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might stumble across this question, like I just did:

> This leaves me with following "missing-prototypes ERROR":
>
> ```
> cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
> cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
> cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
> ```

These lines aren't actually errors. The `make` command runs a bunch of other commands, as specified in a file called `Makefile`. By default, `make` will write out these commands to the terminal before running them. For example, if `Makefile` says to run `foo` then `bar` then `baz`, make will write `foo` to the terminal then run the `foo` command; then it will write `bar` to the terminal and run `bar`; then it will write `baz` to the terminal and run `baz`.

In this case, those `cc` lines are commands that `make` has been told to run by `Makefile`. The `cc` command will run the system's default [C compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers), which is probably [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org). Those things beginning with `-` are [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Option_conventions_in_Unix-like_systems), which affect the behaviour of the C compiler.

For compilers like GCC, [options beginning with `-W`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) tell the compiler to give out warnings when it sees code that's technically valid, but is often a bad idea (e.g. some pattern in the code which many programmers *think* will act in some way, but will actually act in another).

In this case `-Wall` turns on many (not quite all!) of GCC's warnings. `-Wmissing-prototypes` and `-Wstrict-prototypes` turn on extra warnings, to spot problems relating to C's [function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) feature.

Hence, these messages are really telling us that the `cc` command is about to be run, and that (among other things) it should warn us if it thinks the code is dodgy; in particular, if function prototypes are being misused.

GCC warnings look something like this:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:1:5: warning: traditional C rejects ISO C style function definitions [-Wtraditional]
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     ^
```

Since nothing like that appears in your output, no warnings or errors occurred; even *with* these extra `-W` checks enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing a newer kernel although it should be working since correctly since 2.6.30 or a version like that. I'm using it as an AP in kernel `3.13.0-24-generic`, even though i know it is better to install a new kernel. I was using it on `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18.12-vivid/` or a similar one (till my HDD crashed). I can give you details of the one used in the mentioned kernel.

1. depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
2. I have seen the information and hardware capabilities somewhere, but I don't remember where it was
3. It sure is :) Look for compat-wireless